# How to avoid pedantic warnings while using Hexadecimal in Enum?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have an enum like this

```
typedef enum {   
    FIRST,  
    SECOND,  
    THIRD = 0X80000001,  
    FOURTH,  
    FIFTH,  
} STATUS;
```

I am getting a pedantic warning since I am compiling my files with the option `-Wpedantic`:

> warning: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of 'int' [-Wpedantic]

I found that it occurs since when I convert the hex value `0X80000001` to integer it exceeds the unsigned integer limits. My purpose is to have continuous hex values as the status in the enum without this warning. 
I cannot use the macros since this will defy the purpose of having the enums in the first place. What code change will avoid this warning?

Comment: Isn't `enum` a reserved keyword?

Comment: Yes, it creates an enumeration.

Comment: @sunqingyao It is.  And it should be used to create an enumeration, like the OP does.

Comment: I have to ask, why to need values that are outside the range of (signed) int?

Comment: Its like returning an address at which we have the error handling/reporting routine for further processing.

Comment: Simply use and array of `uintptr_t` then... simple `enum` (0,1,2,3...) can be used for indexing the array.

Comment: @LPs, I think `uintptr_t` may be a better choice.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, really better ;)

Comment: I'll just add that you could simply write your definition of both the enum and the table LPs suggested using [X-macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros). That way you'll just have to update the `.def` file when you add a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumeration constants are guaranteed to be of the same size as (signed) `int`. Apparently your system uses 32 bit int, so an unsigned hex literal larger than 0x7FFFFFFF will not fit.

So the warning is not just "pedantic", it hints of a possibly severe bug. Note that `-pedantic` in GCC does *not* mean "be picky and give me unimportant warnings" but rather "ensure that my code actually follows the C standard".

It appears that you want to do a list of bit masks or hardware addresses, or some other hardware-related programming. `enum` is unsuitable for such tasks, because in hardware-related programming, you rarely ever want to use signed types, but always unsigned ones.

If you must have a safe and portable program, then there is no elegant way to do this. C is a language with a lot of flaws, the way `enum` is defined by the standard is one of them.

One work-around is to use some sort of "poor man's enum", such as:

```
typedef uint32_t STATUS;

#define THIRD 0X80000001
```

If you must also have the increased type safety of an enum, then you could possibly use a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t value;
} STATUS;
```

Or alternatively, just declare an array of constants and use an enum to define the array index. Probably the cleanest solution but takes a little bit of extra overhead:

```
typedef enum {   
    FIRST,  
    SECOND,  
    THIRD,  
    FOURTH,  
    FIFTH,  
    STATUS_N
} STATUS; 

const uint32_t STATUS_DATA [STATUS_N] =
{
  0,
  1,
  0X80000001,
  0X80000002,
  0X80000003
};
```

Comment: `Enumeration constants are guaranteed to be of the same size as (signed) int` The standard says: `Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.` That sounds as a conflict to me.

Comment: @4386427 Indeed, that's part of the C language flaw I'm talking about. An _enumeration constant_ is guaranteed to be the same type as `int` (6.7.2.2/3), but an _enumeration type_ (variable) could be any of the mentioned types (6.7.2.2/4). It is plain stupid, but it is a well-known flaw.